# Display symfony form on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I want to make a comment section and I want to have a dynamic reply button, so that after it is clicked, form shows below comment that I want to replay to. I am calling a method with symfony form `{{render(controller('BlogBundle:Comment:new',{'blog_id' : BlogPost.id }))}}` so It`s always displayed in same place. But when I want to replay to a comment, I want to be able to display the form with button click, can I do that by using the same form that I used for the first task ? because I need to have it hidden by default.

This is controller that I am calling now, for displaying the form

```
public function newAction($blog_id)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->setBlog($blog_id);
    $form =  $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);

    return $this->render('BlogBundle:Default:form.html.twig',array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'comment' => $comment
        ));
}
```

This is my form

```
class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('text')
        ->add('send', SubmitType::class, array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'send')));
    }
}
```

And just for button displaying I am doing this

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    {{comment.name}} <div id = "buttonDisplayForm"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Reply</button></div>
    <p>{{comment.text}}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

But I need to somehow display form below `<p>{{comment.text}}</p>` by clicking on button.

Comment: Something like $('#buttonDisplayForm .btn').click(function() { $(this).next('p').show() });

Comment: The main problem is how to put the form there, because I probably can not use `{{render(controller('BlogBundle:Comment:new',{'blog_id' : BlogPost.id }))}}` as it will just always display the form.

Comment: Either you hide the form per default via CSS. Or you render this partial via an AJAX / AJAH action when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `Symfony` itself. As **@axel.michel** pointed out, you could just hide the form.

One way is to wrap your form rendering (starting with `{{ form_start() }}` and  ending with `{{ form_end() }}`) within some hidden `<div>`:

```
<div style="display: none" id="my_form">
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    Rest of your form rendering calls go here...
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

Then it is just a matter of applying something similar to what **@axel.michel** suggested in the first comment.

### UPDATE

```
$(".buttonDisplayForm")
    .on('click', function() { 
        $('#reply_form').append('{{render(controller("BlogBundle:Comm‌​ent:new",{"blog_id‌​": BlogPost.id})) }}')
    });
```

Some key points:

- `{{ render }}` needs to be enclosed with quotes (in my case I chose single quotes)
- `render` operation takes place on server, not on client. Think about it if you really want to use `AJAX` - the `BlogPost.id` will be fixed for all the request.
- Within `render` itself, I choose to use double quotes, in order to minimize potential confusion with what is `Symfony` and what is `JS`

Hope this helps...

Comment: I was trying to do it with ajax, I am able to return my form, but I have a problem to append it to something. Also I tried it withou ajax just like this `$(".buttonDisplayForm").on('click', function() {
             $('#reply_form').append({{render(controller('BlogBundle:Comment:new',{'+'blog_id' : BlogPost.id }))}});` and I don't know how to be able to render the controller, I can append it as string, but it doesn't render then

Comment: Well that is not `AJAX`. The `{{ render }}` tag will get executed and content rendered long before any `JavaScript` is executed. Basically, when user clicks the button, you are appending a very large hunk of text (well, `html` in this case) to your `.buttonDisplayForm`. Not sure if the SO copy and paste went wrong but I think I see what you could be facing. I will update the answer for better look...

Comment: If i use the updated code, it will print text `{{render(controller("BlogBundle:Comm‌​ent:new",{"blog_id‌​": BlogPost.id})) }}` . The fact that `blogPost.id`is same is fine, because it has same value per page.